# What populates Visual Studio Attach to Process Title field?

Tags: visual-studio

In the 'attach to process' window for visual studio, there's a Title field but it's blank for console apps. I'd like to populate this field for my app but don't know how to.

I suspect from reading around that is related to the 'main' application window. I'm happy to create a window and attach a message loop if necessary but it looks like I need to do more than just this.

Any information or advice appreciated! Thanks.